# Japanese IME - How to have menus in English?

Tags: windows-10, japanese

I am using the built-in Japanese IME in Windows 10.  However, now the option settings and menus are all in Japanese.  Is there a way to turn on English for these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Open settings and click Time and Language then click Region & Language then select Add Language and type English in search bar and click on it and a button to download should appear. Download and install it, then you can turn on English.

[image: Settings]

[image: Region&Language]

Comment: Sorry if I left out a bit of information.  My Windows 10 installation is English, and I just want to use the Japanese IME to enter some Japanese text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got English menu back by uninstalling the Japanese Windows display language pack. If you just want to type Japanese you don't need the display language pack installed, just the Japanese input method.

To try this open *control panel* > *languages* and click *Options* for the Japanese language. In the windows display language section click *uninstall language pack* and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The default display language for the Microsoft IME is "Automatic", and occasionally it decides for whatever reason to change from English to Japanese or vice versa.
At any rate, you can correct the issue without removing any language packs via the following steps. I'm going to assume that your Windows display language is in English, but your IME is set to display in Japanese.

1. Navigate thus: Control Panel -> Region & Language -> Keyboards &
   Languages -> Change Keyboards
2. Highlight "Microsoft IME" under the Japanese (Japan) keyboard section of the "Installed services" list
3. Select "Properties"
4. Under the ""全股" tab, you will see an option at the bottom "メニューおよびダイアログで使用する言語" which is the IME display language option. Change this to "英語" (English) and save your changes (the buttons are in the same order as they are in the English UI, "Okay", "Cancel", "Apply", and "Help".

The next time you reopen the IME in the language bar, it should display in English.